# Year changed to 0000 after dateTimeFormat

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

I am trying to convert dateTime from string to org.joda.time.LocalDateTime. The variable actualLocalDateTime in my code below is set to: 0000-03-05T14:00:09.000, instead of 2020-03-05T14:00:09.000. 
What am I missing here?

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.xxxx");
String dateTimeString = "2020-03-05 14:00:09.000000";
LocalDateTime actualLocalDateTime = DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parseLocalDateTime(dateTimeString);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `java.time`? Do you support older versions of java or android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With joda time library.

```
        org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter USPS_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
        String dateTimeString = "2020-03-05 14:00:09.000000";
        org.joda.time.LocalDateTime actualLocalDateTime = USPS_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parseLocalDateTime(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(actualLocalDateTime);
```

Comment: Ahh, replacing the xxxxxx to SSSSS fixed it. Thanks! though still unclear why would it affect the year like so.

Answer (score 3):

### weekyear

> ```
>  Symbol  Meaning                      Presentation  Examples
>  ------  -------                      ------------  -------
>  x       weekyear                     year          1996
> ```

You used `xxxx` to parse what seems to be the fraction of second. Pattern letter `x` is for week-based year. So since the fraction was 0, you were setting the year to 0.

The solution: use `SSSSSS` for fraction of second instead of `xxxx` as shown in the correct answer by Sanjay.

> ```
> S       fraction of second           millis        978
> ```

The documentation says *millis* (so milliseconds), but parsing `.000000` (microseconds) works too. You need to specify the exact number of decimals, so `SSSSSS`. When happens then is that Joda-Time uses the first three decimals for milliseconds and ignores the rest.

**Link:** [Documentation of `DateTimeFormat`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Comment: if you want to fix your code for milliseconds you should use `S`

something like this 

```DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parseLocalDateTime(dateTimeString)```

Comment: Yes, @VikashTiwari, good point. I just edited the answer to include this piece of information.

Comment: Looks so much better now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in earlier answer, you're using wrong syntax for the date string.
`x` is used for week of the year (read [here](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

To solve your problem at hand, you can use

`DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parseLocalDateTime(dateTimeString)`

Comment: Correct. Why are you repeating it?

Comment: oops

I had it drafted and when I was writing it your answer didn't have the necessary changes in format.
But I see now, that you have updated your answer.